# 'ion-progress-bar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to use 'ion-progress-bar' in my ionic app. But it is throwing the below error.

I tried finding solution but somehow not able to resolve. Please suggest where is am doing the mistake.

My home.html looks like below:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-progress-bar></ion-progress-bar>  
</ion-content>
```

In my app.module.ts, i have the below:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
```

The error is as below:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'ion-progress-bar' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-progress-bar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-progress-bar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<!-- <ion-progress-bar value="0.5"></ion-progress-bar> -->

[ERROR ->]<ion-progress-bar></ion-progress-bar>
```

Comment: verify that IonProgressBar is exported in IonicModule and make sure that IonicModule is in your imports array. Also, is your home component in your app.module?

Answer (score 0):

check weather you registered this component IonProgressBar in the app.module.ts like

```
declarations: [
    MyApp ,
    IonProgressBar 
  ]
```

Also in the IonProgressBar .ts file check

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ion-progress-bar',
  ----------------------------
  ----------------------------
})
```

Comment: It is throwing error: Cannot find name 'AppComponent'.ts(2304)
and Cannot find name 'IonProgressBar'.ts(2304)